# Why is my Java application (without a memory leak)getting slower over time

Tags: java, performance, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

So basically I have a java application which gets slower and slower overtime (even if I reset my JVM). There was no memory leakage detected either. The GC works fine after I manipulated the VM options to ( -Xmx1024m).

anyway, what i'm trying to do is to run a for loop with some codes inside for over 40,000 times but it's just getting slower and slower.

The loop is like this (I had to remove the SQL queries for copyright issues):

```
for (int ab = m;ab<=(duration);ab+=600){
    jLabel_current.setText(String.valueOf(ab/600));
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(ab/600));
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(loop));

    try{
        con = datasource.getConnection();   
        for (int i=1;i<=4;i++){

            String sql=" Some query ";
            stmt = con.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                    java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
            System.out.println(sql);
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while(rs.next()){
                int a =rs.getInt("columnName");

                sql="Some query";          
                pst1=con.prepareStatement(sql);
                rs1=pst1.executeQuery();
                if(rs1.next()){                                      
                    x=rs1.getInt("columnName");
                    for(int b=0;b<x;b++){
                        if (loop!=max){
                            int task_id=parseWithDefault((jTable_task_main.getModel().getValueAt(loop, 1).toString()),0);
                            int jobb_id=parseWithDefault((jTable_task_main.getModel().getValueAt(loop, 4).toString()),0);
                            int idk=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(curTimeinner));
                            sql="insert into ";
                            pst2=con.prepareStatement(sql);
                            pst2.setInt(1, a);
                            pst2.setInt(2, rs1.getInt("columnName"));
                            pst2.setInt(3, rs1.getInt("columnName"));
                            pst2.setInt(4, rs1.getInt("columnName"));
                            pst2.setInt(5, rs1.getInt("columnName"));
                            pst2.setDouble(6, rs1.getDouble("columnName"));
                            pst2.setDouble(7, rs1.getDouble("columnName"));
                            pst2.setInt(8, rs1.getInt("columnName"));
                            pst2.setInt(9, rs1.getInt("columnName"));
                            pst2.setInt(10,n);
                            pst2.setInt(11,m); 
                            pst2.setInt(12, g);

                            if(rs1.getLong("columnName")<=curTime){
                                currDuration=endTask-curTimeinner;
                                pst2.setLong(13, endTask);
                                pst2.setLong(14,currDuration );

                                if(rs.getLong("columnName")>endTask){
                                    currTaskOut="successful";
                                    pst2.setString(15, currTaskOut);
                                    pst2.setInt(16, loop);
                                }else{
                                    currTaskOut="unsuccessful";
                                    pst2.setString(15, currTaskOut);
                                    pst2.setInt(16, loop);
                                }

                            }else {
                                endTask2=rs1.getLong("columnName")+120;
                                pst2.setLong(13, endTask2);
                                pst2.setLong(14, currDuration);

                                if(rs.getLong("columnName")>endTask2){
                                    currTaskOut="successful";
                                    pst2.setString(15, currTaskOut);
                                    pst2.setInt(16, loop);
                                }else{
                                    currTaskOut="unsuccessful";
                                    pst2.setString(15, currTaskOut);
                                    pst2.setInt(16, loop);
                                }                                            
                            }

                            pst2.execute();

                            loop+=1;

                            if(loop%4==0){
                                curTimeinner+=600;

                                String outcome=null;
                                String out1 = null;
                                String out2 = null;
                                String out3 = null;
                                String out4 = null;
                                ResultSet rs3=null;
                                for (int bv = 1; bv <= 4; bv++) {
                                    outcome = "unsuccessful";
                                    String sql1 = "select statment";
                                    pst1 = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                                    rs3 = pst1.executeQuery(sql1);
                                    while (rs3.next()) {
                                        if ("successful".equals(rs3.getString("task_outcome"))) {
                                            outcome = "successful";
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (bv == 1) {
                                        out1 = outcome;
                                    } else if (bv == 2) {
                                        out2 = outcome;
                                    } else if (bv == 3) {
                                        out3 = outcome;
                                    } else {
                                        out4 = outcome;

                                        sql = "SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT";
                                        pst1 = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                                        rs3 = pst1.executeQuery(sql);
                                        if (rs3.next()) {
                                            res_id = rs3.getInt("AUTO_INCREMENT");
                                        }

                                        if ("successful".equals(out1) && "successful".equals(out2) && "successful".equals(out3) && "successful".equals(out4)) {
                                            sql = "update statment";
                                            pst1 = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                                            pst1.execute();
                                        } else {
                                            sql = "update statment";
                                            pst1 = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                                            pst1.execute();                                                                          
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    sql="update statment";
                    pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
                    pst.execute(); 
                }
            }
        }
        curTime += 600;
        endTask += 600;
        ab+=600;
        max+=4;

        String sql="update statment";
        pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.execute(); 
        ab-=600;
    }                                   

    catch (SQLException e ) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    } finally {
        try { if (rs != null) rs.close(); } catch(Exception e) { }
        try { if (stmt != null) stmt.close(); } catch(Exception e) { }
        try { if (con != null) con.close(); } catch(Exception e) { }
        try { if (pst != null) pst.close(); } catch(Exception e) { }
        try { if (rs1 != null) rs1.close(); } catch(Exception e) { }
        try { if (pst1 != null) pst1.close(); } catch(Exception e) { }
        try { if (rs2 != null) rs2.close(); } catch(Exception e) { }
        try { if (pst2 != null) pst2.close(); } catch(Exception e) { }
    }  
}
```

And this is the heap dump:

```
Java2D Disposer" daemon prio=10 tid=10 WAITING
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:142)
   Local Variable: java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue#72
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:158)
at sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Disposer.java:148)
   Local Variable: sun.java2d.Disposer#1
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


"SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1" daemon prio=5 tid=21 WAITING
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1245)
at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1319)
at simulator.Main_panel$simulation1.doInBackground(Main_panel.java:896)
at simulator.Main_panel$simulation1.doInBackground(Main_panel.java:876)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:295)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
   Local Variable: javax.swing.SwingWorker$2#1
   Local Variable: javax.swing.SwingWorker$1#1
at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
   Local Variable: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor#1
   Local Variable: simulator.Main_panel$simulation1#1
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
   Local Variable: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker#1
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


"*** Profiler Agent Special Execution Thread 6" daemon prio=5 tid=26 WAITING
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
at      org.netbeans.lib.profiler.server.ProfilerServer$SeparateCmdExecutionThread.run(ProfilerServer.java:289)


"*** JFluid Monitor thread ***" daemon prio=10 tid=25 TIMED_WAITING
at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
at org.netbeans.lib.profiler.server.Monitors$SurvGenAndThreadsMonitor.run(Monitors.java:186)


"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=9 tid=4 RUNNABLE


"TimerQueue" daemon prio=5 tid=20 TIMED_WAITING
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
at    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
   Local Variable: java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$Node#8
   Local Variable: java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject#3
at java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(DelayQueue.java:223)
   Local Variable: java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock#77
   Local Variable: java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue#1
at javax.swing.TimerQueue.run(TimerQueue.java:171)
   Local Variable: javax.swing.TimerQueue#1
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


"Attach Listener" daemon prio=5 tid=5 RUNNABLE


"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=2 WAITING
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:157)


"Thread-1" prio=5 tid=14 RUNNABLE
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
   Local Variable: java.net.SocketInputStream#1
   Local Variable: java.io.FileDescriptor#8
   Local Variable: byte[]#472
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:114)
at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:161)
at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:189)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2549)
   Local Variable: com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream#1
   Local Variable: byte[]#464
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3002)
   Local Variable: com.mysql.jdbc.Buffer#2
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2991)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3532)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
   Local Variable: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO#1
   Local Variable: java.lang.String#287058
   Local Variable: com.mysql.jdbc.Buffer#1
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2618)
   Local Variable: java.lang.String#286257
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2568)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1557)
   Local Variable: com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl#2
   Local Variable: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection#1
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:207)
   Local Variable: org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement#3
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:207)
   Local Variable: org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement#4
at simulator.Main_panel$2.run(Main_panel.java:1011)
   Local Variable: java.lang.String#346303
   Local Variable: java.lang.String#751527


"AWT-Shutdown" prio=5 tid=11 WAITING
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
at sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown.run(AWTAutoShutdown.java:295)
   Local Variable: sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown#1
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


"Finalizer" daemon prio=8 tid=3 WAITING
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:142)
   Local Variable: java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue#82
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:158)
at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)
   Local Variable: java.lang.System$2#1


"AWT-Windows" daemon prio=6 tid=12 RUNNABLE
at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop(Native Method)
at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(WToolkit.java:303)
   Local Variable: sun.awt.windows.WToolkit#1
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


"DestroyJavaVM" prio=5 tid=19 RUNNABLE


"AWT-EventQueue-0" prio=6 tid=16 WAITING
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
   Local Variable: java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject#2
   Local Variable: java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$Node#4
at java.awt.EventQueue.getNextEvent(EventQueue.java:542)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:170)
   Local Variable: java.awt.EventQueue#1
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
   Local Variable: java.awt.EventDispatchThread$HierarchyEventFilter#1
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
   Local Variable: java.awt.EventDispatchThread$1#1
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)


"*** Profiler Agent Communication Thread" daemon prio=10 tid=24 RUNNABLE
at sun.management.HotSpotDiagnostic.dumpHeap0(Native Method)
at sun.management.HotSpotDiagnostic.dumpHeap(HotSpotDiagnostic.java:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   Local Variable: sun.management.HotSpotDiagnostic#2
   Local Variable: sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl#10
   Local Variable: java.lang.Object[]#262773
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.netbeans.lib.profiler.server.system.HeapDump.takeHeapDump16(HeapDump.java:165)
   Local Variable: java.lang.String#751526
at org.netbeans.lib.profiler.server.system.HeapDump.takeHeapDump(HeapDump.java:92)
at org.netbeans.lib.profiler.server.ProfilerServer.handleClientCommand(ProfilerServer.java:1657)
at org.netbeans.lib.profiler.server.ProfilerServer.listenToClient(ProfilerServer.java:1733)
   Local Variable: org.netbeans.lib.profiler.wireprotocol.TakeHeapDumpCommand#1
at org.netbeans.lib.profiler.server.ProfilerServer.run(ProfilerServer.java:690)
```

Comment: stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE) ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew Actually that's what MySQL (possibly some others as well) requires you to set in order to get "don't prefetch everything" behavior.

Comment: OP, how about some courtesy formatting? You make us scroll in both dimensions while trying to make sense of it.

Comment: @Brian Agnew [Read this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html)

Comment: Ooft, that's painful to read. If ever there was a need for a re-factor.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik How about I upload a textfile? I'm really sorry it's my first time using such a long code in here :(

Comment: If you just use your IDE to properly indent the code using two spaces as indent step, you'd make an immense imrovement.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik I'll try my best...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is full of resource leaks, mostly because of reusing a variable for another object instance, hence not closing the prior instance.

- Declare variables as close to their first usage and use **try-with-resources**:

  ```
  String sql1 = "..."
  try (PreparedStatement pst1 = con.prepareStatement(sql1)) {

      for (int a = 0; a < 100; ++a) {
          pst1.setInt(1, a);
          try (ResultSet rs1 = pst1.executeQuery()) {
              while (rs1.next()) {
              }
          } // Safe close of rs1
      }

  } // Safe close of pst1
  ```
- To receive the generated primary key, the AUTO_INCR column, java devised a vendor independant mechanism:

  ```
  String sql1 = "INSERT INTO table(col2, col3) VALUES(?, ?)";
  try (PreparedStatement pst1 = con.prepareStatement(sql1, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS))) {
       int updateCount = pst1.executeUpdate();
       if (updateCount != 0) { // Records inserted?
           int res_id = 0; // Key
           try (ResultSet generatedKeysRS = pst1.getGeneratedKeys()) {
                if (generatedKeysRS.next()) {
                    res_id = generatedKeysRS.getInt(1);
                }
           }
       }
   }
  ```

This solves the concurrency problem, when two inserts take place at the same time, and the new generated key is taken:

```
1. A inserts
2. B inserts
3. B asks generated key
4. A asks generated key
```

And allow me to point out two best practices:

- The code is too long, the numbering like rs1/rs2/rs3 exposes the code to mix-ups. Try to introduce functions. Give meaningfull names.
- The same defensive coding: do not set the **i<sup>th</sup>** column inside if-statements:

  ```
                              int endTask = 0;
                              int currDuration = 0;
                              String currTaskOut = "";
                              if (rs1.getLong("columnName") <= curTime) {
                                  //if (rs.getLong("columnName") > ...) {
                                  endTask = ...;
                                  currDuration = ...;
                              } else {
                                  //...
                              }
                              pst2.setLong(13, endTask);
                              pst2.setLong(14, currDuration);
                              pst2.setString(15, currTaskOut);
                              pst2.setInt(16, loop);
  ```

Comment: Yep try-with-resources is the answer. Thanks a lot, Although you forgot to request for the "generated key" in your preparedstatment.